# Unable to use two component in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am new to **Vue** and i have a problem :

Here is my `index.html` that i use 2 custom tag **aas** and task :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"> 
        <aas></aas>
        <task></task>
    </div>
    <script src="../index/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And my `main.js` :

```
Vue.component('aas', {
        template:'<a><slot></slot></a>'
    });
    Vue.component('task', {
        template:'<li><slot></slot></li>'
    });
    new Vue({
        el:'#root'
    });
```

But i have a error :

```
    vue.js:597 [Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <aas> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

(found in <Root>)
```

Is There a way fix it?!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/feL7ooxb/

Comment: Your code doesn't have the error you describe. https://codepen.io/connexo/pen/QxLVYq?editors=1111

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set a name to in your component:

```
Vue.component('aas', {
  name: 'aas',
  template:'<a><slot></slot></a>'
});
```

According to [this issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/3039#issuecomment-224161673) it should solve that warning.